# JOptionPane handling how it is closed

Tags: java, joptionpane

So I've created a JOptionPane looking like this:

```
public class CustomDifficultyWindow {


public CustomDifficultyWindow(){

    JTextField width = new JTextField();
    JTextField height = new JTextField();
    JTextField bombs = new JTextField();

    Object[] message = {"Breite", width, "Höhe", height, "Bomben",    bombs};

    JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane(message, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
    pane.createDialog(null,"Benutzerdefiniert").setVisible(true);

    System.out.println("Breite: " + width.getText() + ", Höhe:" +  height.getText() + ", Bomben:" + bombs.getText());
}
}
```

I want to handle how the window is closed in another class but in:

```
CustomDifficultyWindow a = new CustomDifficultyWindow();
System.out.println(a);
```

The variable "a" doesnt show how the Window was exited. Basicly with which method i can say if my window was exited with the OK button?

Comment: Which window do you mean? The dialog you created by `pane.createDialog` or the `CustomDifficultyWindow` itself?

Comment: the dialog pane.createDialog

Comment: You can use showConfirmDialog. You can then reference the different close options.

Comment: if i dont create a new pane i cant get three inputs, if I'm not wrong..

Comment: @RobinSchmidt Ok, see my answer. You don't really want to handle this in another class, usually you handle it immediately. If you do want to, you should make your `CustomDifficultyWindow` class extends dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
int returnVal = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(PARENT_WINDOW, "Some message", "Title", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
if (returnVal == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION) {
    // do something if user cancels.
    return;
}

// user pressed confirm(ok)
... handle user input
```

Comment: I see that, but I already got a OK_CANCEL_OPTION in my pane, isnt there a possibility to catch these actions ?

Comment: @RobinSchmidt the thing is `createDialog` only returns a `JDialog` and won't catch these actions. Internally, `showConfirmDialog` is creating an dialog with options, which is the method you should use.